# CustomCell: unable to show data on main view

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, custom-cell

i made a custom cell having a label and an imageView, the custom cell cell has a class customCellClass with an identifier CustomTableCell. 
this is the result screen shot, no data has been passed but the custom table appears as u can see

[image: screen shot]

this is the .m file where im getting the data from an Array *name. please see what am i missing. and btw im trying to [self.tableView reloadData]; in viewdidload but i dont know y, but i cant possible initiate that.

```
@synthesize name = _name;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.name = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third",@"First", @"Second", @"Third",@"First", @"Second", @"Third",@"First", @"Second", @"Third",@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil];
//    self.name = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.name count];

}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";


    customCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[customCellClass alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = [self.name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageThumb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"];
    return  cell;


}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}


@end
```

btw this is the custom table cell im using

[image]

Comment: have you assigned delegate and datasource to table??

Comment: datacource and delegate ......?

Comment: Are you sure, your outlet connections are  correct?

Comment: yup, all clear in the outlets and the delegates and the sources too. i tried running it without the customcell before and it worked perfectly. but after adding the customcell it just show as it is like in the pic.

Comment: why is the 'super' call in viewDidLoad missing? and have you already set a breakpoint in cellForRow... ?

Comment: Just check the self.name count value .

Comment: in viewdidload its just the array value declared there and nothing else. and will try to do what u guys told me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doing `alloc init` and then check it to nil... in you case you never pass this `if`

```
 cell = [[customCellClass alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

Just do it:

```
customCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[customCellClass alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
```

Comment: im having this exception   

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/macpro/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/6AD202CD-7BDC-4E09-B3E0-B7A13C30BC69/CustomTableViewAce.app> (loaded)' with name 'CustomTableCell''

Comment: So before you even never try to load yuor cell!

Comment: Check name of custom cell

Comment: customCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
Looks like customCellClass with lowercase "c"

Comment: done it!! thanx for all the replz. i loaded the freaking wrong nib name. thats all.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

Create Class File like this:

**CustomRankingCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomRankingCell : UITableViewCell

+(UITableViewCell *) cellFromNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName;

@end
```

**CustomRankingCell.m**

```
#import "CustomRankingCell.h"

@implementation CustomRankingCell



+ (CustomRankingCell *)cellFromNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName {

    NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:NULL];
    NSEnumerator *nibEnumerator = [nibContents objectEnumerator];
    CustomRankingCell *xibBasedCell = nil;
    NSObject* nibItem = nil;

    while ((nibItem = [nibEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) {
        if ([nibItem isKindOfClass:[CustomRankingCell class]]) {
            xibBasedCell = (CustomRankingCell *)nibItem;
            break; // we have a winner
        }
    }

    return xibBasedCell;
}


@end
```

And extend your custom cell by CustomRankingCell rather than UITableViewCell like this

```
#import "CustomRankingCell.h"

@interface RankingCell : CustomRankingCell
{

}
```

and then use custom cell like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RankingCell";

RankingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = (RankingCell *)[RankingCell cellFromNibNamed:@"RankingCell"];
}
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: just the same result. thanx for the reply too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for my custom cell in a table and it works perfectly.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.name count];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    mycustomcell *cell = (mycustomcell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"mycustomcell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog( @"NIB = %@",nib);
        NSLog( @"Cell = %@",cell);
    }

    cell.txtData.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

            cell.imgThumb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"];
            cell.txtData.enabled=NO;


    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

try this hope help for you..

Comment: here mucustomecell is customecell implement and you can get data in label "name" instead of textfield "txtData"..

Comment: this is the code that i just implemented. only [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone]; is the one missing, but will try this too

Comment: so please check you customecell.xib connections.